# Grid design on a master page

Tags: 2013, design

We are trying to use a grid design on a master page in SharePoint 2013 / Office 365. This will imitate the default title bar + side nav bar but with a third party framework. The reason I am asking here is because it seems to be framework independent for our issue. Basically we only want the ContentPlaceHolderMain to show in a dialog as per normal. But, with a grid framework we have a column for the side nav bar and a column for the content placeholder within the same row. When we add the ns-dialogHidden to the side nav it hides all the data but the page width is still taken up in the dialog.

Any ideas of how to get around this? A simple way would be to test if the "page" is within a dialog box and write Sass code to modify the columns. I did not see a way to do this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it might help you, but the root **HTML** tag in SharePoint 2013 contains a class **ms-dialog** when the page is opened as a pop-up:

[image]

This might help you to apply certain styles only to the pages that are opened in dialog boxes in the CSS like so:

```
.ms-dialog .myNavBar{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: the ms-dialogHidden takes care of hidding the contents of the div in our grid (we're using foundation and small-2 columns for this one) but the column space is still taken up. Are you suggesting something similar to .ms-dialog .small-2 colums {display:none;} ? For production we're going to play with Sass and not use the default class names of course.

Comment: I think you should not avoid using standard class names unless you want to remove a link to standard core.css file from your master page. Can you go to built-in browser's developer tools via F12 and click on the big white area that is being taken up? I think you've hidden your column but something else is taking up the space. You can even post a post a few screenshots so that we can understand what's your problem specifically.

Comment: Here's a link to an example: http://imgur.com/a/3dIzt
As you can see, in the dialog part the content of the green column is gone but the spacing is still there. If it's not easy to tell, the left side of the red bg should be much further to the left.
edit:
For ease of comparison http://imgur.com/aUBGTSn

Comment: Well, that's a very easy thing to fix, but you need to inspect the HTML of the white area on the left with your built in Web Developer Tools. When you identify the problem, you can write some CSS that only targets dialog boxes. In order to fix this problem and NOT break your pages that are not displayed in the dialog boxes I suggest you use the example I've included in the answer. For Instance. Suppose your white area to to the left is  margin-left:90px for the div with class='someDiv'. Then you will have to include CSS that looks like so: .ms-dialog .someDiv {margin-left:0 !important }

Comment: Basically, you need to show your problem to a guy that knows some CSS and HTML. I'm sure he will look and tell you how to fix it within a minute. This problem is pretty hard to tackle via the forums.

Comment: It wasn't a margin issue. I did find where the column width was still set though. Trying to fix it in CSS by using a space between the two classes isn't working quite yet, but you at least got me started. Thank you very much!

Comment: Would upvote but not enough rep =\

Comment: that's alright, tanwedar. I hope I helped somehow.